# Suggestion for the numerical solution of a nonlinear pde system.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I am faced with the following system of coupled nonlinear partial differential equations
$$
\begin{array}{lcccl}
\varphi_{tt} &-& a_1\varphi_{xx} &+& a_2\varphi_t &=& a_3\sin{\varphi} + a_4\sin{\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)} + a_5u_x\sin{\varphi} + a_6v_x\cos{\varphi} + a_7\sin{(\omega t)},\\
u_{tt} &-& b_1u_{xx} &+& b_2u_t &=& b_3(\cos{\varphi})_x, \\
v_{tt} &-& c_1v_{xx} &+& c_2v_t &=& c_3(\sin{\varphi})_x,
\end{array}
$$
where $a_k,b_k,c_k\in\mathbb{R},~a_1,b_1,c_1>0.$

What ideas might here be for numerically solving this system?

**UPD1. Regarding to Chris' question.**

Parameter $\omega$ is also constant, same as $a_k,b_k,c_k.$
Indeed, $\left(\cos{\varphi}\right)_x=-\varphi_x\sin{\varphi}.$

I thought to numerically investigate the soliton propagation, and the initial and boundary conditions may follow from here.

I haven't written down the difference approximation yet because, perhaps, it's not the central differences that need to be applied, but upwind-type schemes that I don't know yet.

Comment: Could you add a bit of context to the question? I assume $a_k,b_k,c_k,\omega$ are constants. Is $(\cos \varphi)_x$ the same as $-\varphi_x \sin \varphi$? What have you tried? What conditions do you have? (Initial, boundary...you'll need those to be defined before you can do anything very useful numerically.) My first thought on this would be that it looks susceptible to a finite difference method, but it will depend a lot on the answers to the other questions.

Comment: @ChrisLewis, I updated my post regarding to your questions. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I would still suggest trying finite differences; you should be able to investigate stability of the method once you have it written down, but my guess would be there will be restrictions on the constants. You'll definitely need to look at initial/boundary conditions, though, as these will dictate how you can iterate the method. It's a while since I've done this sort of thing, perhaps others will have better suggestions.